# Template file for Views exposed filter block

Tags: views, theming, blocks

Views has a great feature where you can expose the exposed filters as a block (**Exposed form in block** under **Exposed form**).

So what's the "standard" way to theme these?  Is there a Views template for this (I couldn't find one), or do I theme it with a renamed block.tpl.php?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, although the exposed filter block does not have any template file in the list under **Theming information**, you can theme it with a views template file like this:

`views-exposed-form--MYVIEWNAME.tpl.php`

There is an example `views-exposed-form.tpl.php` in the Views module theme directory.

Comment: The same seems to be true for Drupal 8 (does not suggest theme hook), but instead of tpl.php you create a new twig template in the templates folder of your theme: views-exposed-form--MY-VIEW-NAME.html.twig

Comment: Just to say thanks and confirm that the way pointed by @JensWegar is working on D8.6.